Python Telegram Message forwarder not forwarding messages properly
The below is the Python code i wrote to forward/copy messages from one group/channel to another. I am facing a problem. when i run the code on pc, the messages are only forwarded to destination group/channel when only if i open source group/channel on my phone. other wise even if the source group/channel have new messages it wont forward. anyone can tell what is the problem
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerUser, InputPeerChannel
from telethon.errors import SessionPasswordNeededError, FloodWaitError
import logging
import json

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class TelegramForwarder:
    def __init__(self, api_id, api_hash, phone_number):
        self.api_id = api_id
        self.api_hash = api_hash
        self.phone_number = phone_number
        self.client = TelegramClient(f'session_{phone_number}', api_id, api_hash)

    async def connect(self):
        await self.client.start()
        if not await self.client.is_user_authorized():
            try:
                await self.client.send_code_request(self.phone_number)
                code = input('Enter the code: ')
                await self.client.sign_in(self.phone_number, code)
            except SessionPasswordNeededError:
                password = input('Two-step verification is enabled. Please enter your password: ')
                await self.client.sign_in(password=password)

    async def list_chats(self):
        await self.connect()
        dialogs = await self.client.get_dialogs()
        chats = []
        for dialog in dialogs:
            chat_info = {
                "id": dialog.id,
                "title": dialog.title,
                "type": "Channel" if dialog.is_channel else "Group" if dialog.is_group else "User"
            }
            chats.append(chat_info)
            logger.info(f"Chat ID: {dialog.id}, Title: {dialog.title}, Type: {chat_info['type']}")
        
        with open(f"chats_of_{self.phone_number}.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(chats, f, indent=4)
        logger.info(f"Chat list saved to chats_of_{self.phone_number}.json")

    async def forward_messages(self, source_chat_id, destination_chat_id, keywords=None):
        await self.connect()
        
        @self.client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=[source_chat_id]))
        async def handler(event):
            try:
                if keywords:
                    if event.message.text and any(keyword.lower() in event.message.text.lower() for keyword in keywords):
                        logger.info(f"Forwarding message: {event.message.text[:50]}...")
                        await self.client.send_message(destination_chat_id, event.message)
                else:
                    logger.info(f"Forwarding message: {event.message.text[:50]}...")
                    await self.client.send_message(destination_chat_id, event.message)
            except FloodWaitError as e:
                logger.warning(f"FloodWaitError: Waiting for {e.seconds} seconds")
                await asyncio.sleep(e.seconds)
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(f"Error forwarding message: {str(e)}")

        logger.info("Started forwarding messages")
        await self.client.run_until_disconnected()

def read_credentials():
    try:
        with open("credentials.json", "r") as file:
            creds = json.load(file)
            return creds["api_id"], creds["api_hash"], creds["phone_number"]
    except FileNotFoundError:
        logger.error("Credentials file not found.")
        return None, None, None

def write_credentials(api_id, api_hash, phone_number):
    creds = {
        "api_id": api_id,
        "api_hash": api_hash,
        "phone_number": phone_number
    }
    with open("credentials.json", "w") as file:
        json.dump(creds, file, indent=4)

async def main():
    api_id, api_hash, phone_number = read_credentials()

    if api_id is None or api_hash is None or phone_number is None:
        api_id = input("Enter your API ID: ")
        api_hash = input("Enter your API Hash: ")
        phone_number = input("Enter your phone number: ")
        write_credentials(api_id, api_hash, phone_number)

    forwarder = TelegramForwarder(api_id, api_hash, phone_number)
    
    while True:
        print("\nChoose an option:")
        print("1. List Chats")
        print("2. Forward Messages")
        print("3. Exit")
        
        choice = input("Enter your choice: ")
        
        if choice == "1":
            await forwarder.list_chats()
        elif choice == "2":
            source_chat_id = int(input("Enter the source chat ID: "))
            destination_chat_id = int(input("Enter the destination chat ID: "))
            keywords = input("Enter keywords (comma-separated) or leave blank: ").split(",") if input("Use keywords? (y/n): ").lower() == 'y' else None
            await forwarder.forward_messages(source_chat_id, destination_chat_id, keywords)
        elif choice == "3":
            print("Exiting...")
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid choice. Please try again.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

